# How to use forward declaration in C?

Tags: c, typedef, forward-declaration

I am writing a C program, and I couldn't find an equivalent example on Stack Overflow. I have 2 files, level.h, lib.h, which depends on the type defined in the other's file. This generates an error, `redefinition of typedef 'metalevel_t'/'entry_t' is a C11 feature`.

level.h:

```
#ifndef level_H
#define level_H
#include "lib.h"

// level.h
typedef struct metalevel metalevel_t; 


// key value pairs, value are integers 
typedef struct entry {
    ...
} entry_t;
```

lib.h:

```
typedef struct entry entry_t;
typedef struct metalevel{
    entry_t* ...; 
} metalevel_t;

metalevel_t Info[...];
```

However, if I replace entry_t (and metalevel_t) with below, I get `typedef requires a name` errors.

```
struct entry {
    ...
};
```

My Makefile looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
CFLAGS=-std=c99
LDFLAGS = -lm

macro_main: macro_main.o lsm.o lib.o level.o
    $(CC) -o macro_main macro_main.o lsm.o lib.o level.o $(CFLAGS) 

macro_main.o: 

clean: 
      $(RM) macro_main
```

How can I use forward declaration in this case?

Comment: Remove `typedef struct metalevel metalevel_t;` from `level.h`.    That file includes `lib.h` anyway so it can see the existing typedef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

level.h:

```
#include "lib.h"

struct entry {
    // ...
};
```

lib.h:

```
typedef struct entry entry_t;
typedef struct metalevel{
    entry_t* p;
} metalevel_t;
```

Not sure what you meant by `metalevel_t Info[...];` , that is likely to lead to an error for any possible contents of the `...` .

Comment: sorry if that is misleading. "..." in metalevel_t Info[...] is some predefined size.

Comment: @Pippi: are you declaring that array in the header? If you are, then every source file that includes that header will end up redeclaring it (which is bad).

Comment: @Pippi It should be `extern metalevel_t Info[5];` in that case

Comment: Thx! I tried this solution, it got rid of `entry_t` error, but not `metalevel_t` error: `redefinition of typedef 'metalevel_t' is a C11 feature`

Comment: @Pippi that means your code is not how I suggested. (Make sure lib.h and level.h both have include guards, I omitted them for brevity)

Comment: yes I forgot to delete metalevel typedef in level.h. Thank you!!